# Should movie trivia questions be closed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should we allow questions that are intended for trivia?

e.g:

- Who played **_ in __** movie / tv ?
- How many seasons did *_* have?
- Who produced __ show?
- What was that movie that had *_*_ (person) in it?

Comment: 3 of these questions can be quickly answered using IMDB, and the 'how many seasons' would probably be answered on Wikipedia if not on IMDB.  We should not attempt to be a poor duplicate of these sites.

Comment: @iandotkelly 'Can' != 'Are'. Most extras are uncredited and won't appear on IMDb.

Comment: @CrowTRobot - and where do I state otherwise? "Who played _ in _ movie/tv show" indicates a named character.

Comment: @iandotkelly `3 of these questions can be quickly answered using IMDB`, and the blank doesn't indicate you were only talking about named characters. Regardless of what the intention of this question was, it's being used incorrectly: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24344/who-is-this-actor-in-the-picture

Comment: @CrowTRobot - oh I see, I didn't know you were referring to a specific question, I just got alerted to your comment here.

Comment: Does [this question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44271/8411) count as "trivia"? It certainly doesn't seem to fit the mold of your example questions, and I don't think it can be answered by IMDB, but at least one person has marked it as "trivia."

Comment: **Trivia questions are *no longer considered off-topic* by the community**, according to a more recent (more than 10 years later) community consensus expressed in this Oct. 2022 meta post:  [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006) and [We're retiring the "trivia" close-reason](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/1006) (The most recent community consensus and policy on the same topic.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [We're retiring the "trivia" close-reason](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4901/were-retiring-the-trivia-close-reason)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4874/which-trivia-questions-are-on-topic-and-which-are-off-topic)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is stated in the [**FAQ**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/faq) that:

> Banal trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.

Is considered **off-topic**.

Comment: **Trivia questions are *no longer considered off-topic* by the community**, according to a more recent (more than 10 years later) community consensus expressed in this Oct. 2022 meta post:  [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006)

Answer (score 5):

The examples given were "trivial" enough to be closed.

I tried to edit [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31671/what-is-the-name-of-the-russian-song-in-the-season-3-episode-3) by asking for the significance of the song.  The answer was a very good one, because it not only identified the song, but gave the underlying context, about the courtship of a peddler and a girl. I added a comment that perhaps the metaphor could be extended further, to the "courtship" of the Russian and American presidents.

Songs are (usually) put into movies for a reason, and if the question asks for the context/meaning of the song (within the movie) as opposed to "identify" this song, it might be a very good question. Other, non-trivial questions that might "add to the understanding of the title" might be, who played in/produced movie X, followed by "What other movies (or types of movies) did this person play in/produce?"

Answer (score 0):

I think the examples given do not relate so much to the question. The examples could all be googled, most of the time quickly and effectively - it's more of a case of [lmgtfy](https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1GGGE_en-gbGB425GB454&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=lmgtfy) than of being off-topic.