# Why was the "Songs sung in Beetlejuice (1988)" question deleted?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, deleted-questions

Why was the ["Songs sung in Beetlejuice (1988)" question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/119290/24580) ([Internet Archive mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20230103140304/https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/119290/songs-sung-in-beetlejuice-1988)) deleted?

Screenshot:
[image]

I thought that a general (Stack Exchange's, cross-site) rule of thumb says that:

- We're *deleting* questions of **very poor quality** only.
- We're *closing* **off-topic** questions.

What is the reason for *deleting* this question? Why was *closing* it not enough?

Especially given the fact that:

- [An answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/119291/24580) to this question got over 10 upvotes.
- The "on-topicness" of this question [was discussed on meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4897/24580), where the [current top-voted answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4897/) suggested that this question should not have been closed in the first place.
- Trivia questions are no longer off-topic as per community consensus: [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4874/which-trivia-questions-are-on-topic-and-which-are-off-topic) |  [We're retiring the "trivia" close-reason](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4901/were-retiring-the-trivia-close-reason)

Wasn't the deletion of this question a bit too harsh a decision? I'd say that it was way too harsh. And it has nothing to do with the fact that I am the author of the deleted question (no personal or emotional part).

It's just that I've been with Stack Exchange for 10+ years, I have 80+ accounts with more or less frequent activity, and I've barely seen maybe **two or three questions that were deleted because they were off-topic and not because they were of very poor quality, offending, hate speech, etc.**

And I've seen hundreds, if not thousands, of off-topic questions that were simply closed.

Comment: On topicness is not being discussed but the help section text. ID were made off topic after a long troubling past with lost of inputs and discussions.

Comment: (1) I thought that there's a pending discussion whether identifying music, songs and other addendum in movies is or isn't on topic. I know that "pure movie ID" is off-topic for a long time here, but my deleted question asks about addendum, not the movie itself.

Comment: (2) Your linked answer starts with the sentence saying: "_Yes, if the question has been closed without improvements and stayed closed **for a significant time** (SE uses 9 days as a measure)_" (emphasis mine). My question in topic was deleted after **less than 48 hours** giving me virtually no time to improve it (sorry, but I don't live and breath Movies & TV, I have other obligations). So, your linked answer does not answer my question. Rephrasing to focus on time and voting to reopen.

Comment: (3) I still think that deleting questions is very rude, that it should be use to very, very poor or wrong questions only and that closing question is far enough (similar thinking on a very significant sister sites across entire SE). This is also a completely pointless and non-sense, because deleted questions can only be seen by high-ranking users and the main idea for closing is that such questions appears in search results and others does not post duplicates. That's the key reason, why closing vs. deleting was invented in SE for the first place.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Because the question's on-topicness is currently being discussed/disputed here: [ID Questions - better info in the Help pages](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4896/1006) — it is bad form to delete it right away. I'm requesting that it be undeleted while the community discusses its on-topicness. This will also give users the opportunity to vote on whether it should be reopened.

Comment: I agree with you 100%.  Users and mods (one mod in particular) have an absolute panic attack when they see _anything_ resembling an ID question.  I'm sorry that you have had a negative experience here.  It makes me sad to see what has become of this site because of stuff like this

Comment: Sorry, but how is your question not "very, very poor" when the answer is *in the movie's credits*? Plus it can be easily googled. Plus it is easily found in IMDb. Plus it is on the movie's Wikipedia page. There literally is a soundtrack album with both songs! That ten people upvoted your question, is irrelevant. Also, you now have written a **400 word** meta question: why couldn't you spend that effort on figuring out the answer to your question in the first place? Especially when it takes no effort to find the answer.

Comment: (1) In the SE that I've been so far, "very, very poor answer" term is all about language and text quality, never about content. It's an answer that has a very basic language problem and is nearly completely not readable. That's why a "very poor quality" close reason **is separate** from other close reasons like "off-topic" or "too broad". Serious users of SE never combine "quality" with "content". (2) If you say that the fact that 10 users upvoted my question is irrelevant clearly means that you completely misunderstand the idea and the mission of SE. In SE community is **everything**.

Comment: (2 cont.) Look for all those questions in the SE or StackExchange that has even a special addendum saying something like "this is very wrong questions in terms of SE quality, but it is kept for historical reasons or because it is **highly upvoted**". Community and votes are all in SE. Being off-topic, not following site rules or having language problem always comes as secondary citizen. (3) My meta question was asked hours **after** I asked question about songs in "Beetlejuice". Suggesting that I could spend this time looking for answer that I already knew by then is a pure non-sense, sorry.

Comment: (4) Saying that something is in the movie credits is a poor quality argument, because I could have a copy of movie without end credits. Googling for song is also poor argument, because it most likely return results about soundtrack, where I can possible be asking about song sing in movie that is _not_ in the soundtrack (like someone whistling something). And of all of above: You can literally google _everything_. If we will be saying that you can google this or that for every or nearly every question asked here then we start asking ourselves what is the reason for this site to exists, right?

Comment: @trejder I made a significant [revision](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/4898/revisions) to this meta post that should now be sufficient to have it reopened. I’ve also voted to reopen it. I made it specific to the question that you referred to and cited recent relevant meta posts. I also added other relevant information. Hopefully, this is enough to get this meta post reopened.

Comment: @galacticninja Thank you for your time and effort! Pity that all that I could do was to cast another vote to reopen.