# The trivia close reason is no longer valid. Please reopen "What does Marty Jr. yell while crossing the street in BTTF2?"

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

I would like to request the reopening of the question, [What does Marty Jr yell while crossing the street in BTTF2?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/116115/1006) This question is currently closed as “trivia”. It recently got reopen votes; however, it was [unilaterally left closed in the reopen review queue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/94938) as “Original close reason(s) were not resolved” by a community moderator, preventing reviewers from seeing it in the reopen review queue.

As [the OP has pointed out in the comments](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/116115/what-does-marty-jr-yell-while-crossing-the-street-in-bttf2#comment200340_116115), we have many similar questions that are open and well-received on the site:

> There are many “what does this character say” questions throughout the forum (the “related” column on this page is full of them).

Like the [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/118042/1006) mentioned in the meta post, [Why did a moderator keep the question about identifying a painting in Eternals closed?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4931/1006) (which has now been reopened by the community), keeping the question closed is contrary to community consensus. [The community has changed its stance to now allow “trivia” questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006), and [the “trivia” close reason is no longer valid](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/1006). The question is interesting and has potential value for future visitors who might be curious about the same thing.

I request the moderators and the community to reconsider this question and vote to reopen it: [What does Marty Jr yell while crossing the street in BTTF2?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/116115/1006)

Related meta posts:

- [Why did a moderator keep the question about identifying a painting in Eternals closed?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4931/1006)
- [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006)
- [Can we please redefine "trivia"?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1827/1006)
- [The term "trivia" is just lazy. Can't we do better?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4514/1006)
- [We're retiring the "trivia" close-reason](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/1006)

Comment: It's been reopened now

Answer (score -3, accepted):

<sup>(I wrote an answer to avoid the [automatic deletion of this meta discussion post by the Community bot (AKA "Roomba")](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/162827). Since it’s currently negatively scored, had no one written an answer, the meta post would have been automatically deleted, dismissing it entirely.)</sup>

As of July 20, 2023, the question "[What does Marty Jr yell while crossing the street in BTTF2?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/116115/1006)" has been reopened, respecting the community consensus on "trivia" questions. Thanks to everyone who participated in the voting.