# Requesting the reopening of "What is the painting J. Paul Getty buys in 'All the Money in the World'?"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, trivia

I think the question, “[What is the painting J. Paul Getty buys in 'All the Money in the World'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/84999/1006)”, deserves to be reopened. It was closed as off-topic for being a trivia question, but that’s not a valid close reason anymore.

[The community changed its position on trivia questions years ago and decided to allow them](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006), so [the trivia close reason is no longer applicable](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/1006). The question has value, and it does not fall under any of our existing close reasons. It could enhance the appreciation of the film for others who may have a similar query.

The question is similar to the one mentioned in the meta post: “[Why did a moderator keep the question about identifying a painting in Eternals closed?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4931/1006)” - which was reopened by the community.

I’m concerned that [its reopen votes will expire soon](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/96102). I believe at least 5 users have voted to reopen, but one or more votes have already expired. Can we please get some more votes to reopen this question, or at least a clear explanation of why it’s still off-topic?

Here are some of the meta posts where the community agreed to stop closing trivia questions as off-topic:

- [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006)
- [Can we please redefine "trivia"?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1827/1006)
- [The term "trivia" is just lazy. Can't we do better?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4514/1006)
- [We're retiring the "trivia" close-reason](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/1006)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been reopened.

https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/84999/timeline

Comment: Thank you to everyone who voted to reopen. Fun fact: 7 users voted to reopen the question. (2 reopen votes have expired.)