# Can I ask for help identifying a piece of music in a TV series episode?

Tags: discussion, scope, music-identification

I want to identify a musical piece played by a character in a TV series episode. Would such a question be on topic? If not, could you potentially suggest where I could look for such information?

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes, it's on-topic.

A similar issue has been raised in these prior meta posts:

- [ID Questions - better info in the Help pages](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4896/1006)
- [Why was the "Songs sung in Beetlejuice (1988)" question deleted?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4898/1006)

I've wrote [an answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4897/1006) to the first meta post listed above (currently the top-voted), so I'll just repeat some of the points I've already made there.

I've started a meta discussion post about identifying songs/music in movies back in 2012: [Should questions about which artist sang or played a song or music in a movie be allowed?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/398/1006) (If I'm not mistaken, this was the first meta discussion post here about identifying movie songs/music.) Two of the three answers to my meta post stated that identifying songs/music in movies is considered "trivia" and thus (was) off-topic, while the current top-voted answer stated that it is acceptable and not "trivia."

**However**, regardless of whether it’s considered trivia or not, **according to the community consensus from Oct. 2022, trivia questions are no longer considered off-topic**. You can find the relevant meta posts here: [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006) and [We're retiring the "trivia" close-reason](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/1006). (The current close vote reasons reflect the community consensus that "trivia" should no longer be a close vote reason, but the moderators have not updated the [“What topics can I ask about here?” help center article](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the [site tour](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) yet.)

Asking about songs or music in movies or TV shows can enhance the appreciation of the movie or TV show.

**Only questions that ask to identify movies and TV shows (and episodes) from a description are considered off-topic in Movies & TV SE.** For example, questions like “I remember [something] about a movie / TV show; what movie / TV show was this?” are closed as off-topic here. As far as I know, **there is *no* community consensus to ban *all* questions that involve identifying something about a movie or TV show**.