# I don't understand why this was off topic

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I understand and accept the voting rules, several people have flagged my post as off topic, but nobody has explained why it is off topic. I just don't understand why a question about where a character lives is off topic and would like further clarification.

I tagged my post 'character' which states 'Typically questions about a specific character in a movie/tv show.' which it was, and also 'star wars' which states 'Use this tag when asking questions about Star Wars.', which I was.

The question is very specifically asking about where a character lives, but some users seemed to misunderstand and think I was asking for a joke explanation. I thought it was perfectly clear but there were no suggested edits and no constructive comments relating to any downvotes or close votes.

I feel it would be far more friendly and constructive to encourage people to improve their question instead of silently voting to close it. Only one person even attempted to explain and it turns out that person had misinterpreted the question, but was blunt and unhelpful regarding improvement of my wording.

The question I refer to is here [Did Yoda live on a hill?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92863/did-yoda-live-on-a-hill/92864)

Comment: It took me like 4 reads of your question to get your joke. But it does seem like you were asking where Yoda lives. I can't speak for downvotes but I can give my 1 vote to reopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while the current close reason i would believe is incorrect as it seems to be about a movie. if the question was re-opened i would vote to close as Off-topic anyway as being

> Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.

Source: [Help Centre > What topics can I ask about here?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

now to me, this joke (which i don't really get) is just noise and noise distracts from the actual question, which given the incorrect close reason for the question is perfect evidence that the joke distracted 5 high rep users from your actual question

after we remove the joke all that's left is really just a repeat of the question title, ***Did Yoda live on a hill?***

as per the close-message for trivia

> Trivia questions that do not add to the understanding or appreciation of a movie/TV-show are off-topic; [We're not trying to duplicate IMDB](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/306/49). Please try to explain why your question is relevant for understanding the work [beyond banal minutiae](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/whats-trivia-and-where-do-we-draw-the-line/55#55).

and in the question's current form or with the noise removed, i can not see how knowing if Yoda lived on a hill or not adds any understanding or appreciation to the movie's plot

Comment: This is the answer I needed. Thank you. It is unfortunate and frustrating that moderators could not follow the rules as well as you can

Comment: Seriously, you don't get the joke? Yoda-Lay-Hee-Hoo? Man, I think it's pretty funny.

Comment: @DarrenH What moderators? There were *zero* moderators involved in handling your question so far.