# Question suddenly closed

Tags: support, closed-questions

I asked [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73933/what-type-of-knot-do-wayfinders-tie-in-moana) about three years ago, and the answer helped me [understand the scene better](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/307/4206), as [this comment](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73933/what-type-of-knot-do-wayfinders-tie-in-moana/106675#comment119886_73934) also illustrates. The question has garnered 16 upvotes in the meantime.

Today, the question was abruptly closed after it has received an allegedly spam answer. Have the guidelines changed since 2017, or what am I missing here? The "private feedback" seems boilerplate and doesn't help me understand what I did wrong.

[image: question brutally closed]

Comment: There's actually a [five-year-old meta consensus](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1827/27759) to abolish the trivia close reason altogether, but the mods never enacted it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Reducing it to votes and a single selected sentence from one of the answers and calling that a "consensus" the moderators ought to oblige might be oversimplifying that meta discussion quite a bit (and ignoring the wealth of other discussions since then).

Answer (score 1):

> Have the guidelines changed since 2017, or what am I missing here?

Not as far as I know **but** the community has become a little more strict about what constitues TRIVIA in the intervening period.

From the help page...

> Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.

What the knot is,  essentially, is **unimportant** to the film overall and so, when the question received more attention (due the spamish post) it started to receive close votes.

When the question appeared in the review queue it was reconsidered and 5 users (myself included) decided that this was, indeed, *trivia*.

Answer (score -4):

I'll weigh in as I was the one that started this train.

The question, title and body, boil down to: what is this knot?  It also has the image.  The question does absolutely nothing to tie (pun may or may knot intended) this piece of trivia to the plot of the movie, or any character development, or honestly even a cultural understanding of what they're doing.  The question doesn't seek to deepen any appreciation for the movie, but rather seeks trivial, surface level information.

And AJ's answer on the question is a perfect indicator of this.  It answers the question exactly, telling us what that knot it.  However, his answer adds **ABSOLUTELY NOTHING OF VALUE** to the movie itself (I know that sounds harsh).

The reason that we, the community, have wanted to steer away from these sort of questions has always been (at least imho) 1. they're boring and 2. clog up the system from actual, deep questions and answers.

Now, with the positive score of the question, even if it remains closed it will not be auto-deleted from the site.  If it stays closed, that just shows that, at one point we appreciated the question, but we've since moved on.  The question does, currently, have 4 reopen votes, which I personally disagree with, but ti could be reopened.