# Please update the site's close reasons, site tour, and help center to reflect the community consensus that trivia questions are no longer off-topic

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, policy, trivia

It's been almost 3 months since the meta post, [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006) (+15/0 votes) was posted. It currently has two answers (+19/-1 and +11/-1 votes) stating that the trivia questions rule should be removed, indicating community consensus on site policy.

Before that meta post, there were already two other meta posts suggesting a similar sentiment: [Can we please redefine "trivia"?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1827/1006) (2015) (Question votes: +31/0; Answer votes: +19/-4) and [The term "trivia" is just lazy. Can't we do better?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4514/1006) (2019) (Question votes: +14/-2).

I've seen several "trivia" close votes since [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006) was posted and I believe some questions were closed as trivia, despite community consensus that the trivia questions rule should be removed. *Since the community consensus has been established, this post serves as a request to the mods that the policy change now be implemented.* **Please update the site's close reasons, [site tour](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour), and [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to *remove references to the trivia rule and reflect the community consensus that trivia questions are no longer off-topic.***

Also, these two meta posts (one of which is a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)-tagged question) that are currently linked to in the trivia close vote reason should be closed and made a duplicate of [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006) to reflect the current community consensus on the topic:

- [Should movie trivia questions be closed?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/306/1006) (The [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag should be removed from this post.)
- [What's trivia and where do we draw the line?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/43/1006)

Comment: The close-reason is gone, sorry it took so long. However, adjustments to the tour and help center are still under consideration as this is ultimately still not what this site is for. They might be adapted for a more stringent definition, but for now I'd refrain from encouraging these questions. So no, please don't go ask what shampoo DiCaprio's dog is using in that one scene. But also don't lynch people who do on sight.

Comment: Done.  We can still revisit this if we want to consider other wording, but it shouldn't remain this inaccurate.

Comment: @iandotkelly Thanks!

Comment: @iandotkelly Also, could you please mark those two meta posts I referred to in this meta post as duplicates of “[Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006)”? This way, we can connect the old meta discussions about trivia questions to our latest one on the topic.